# How do I find the length of the input string even though i set the size of array

Tags: c

How do I find how many numbers the user inputs if I already set the size to 20

`strlen` would only get me 20 still

and how would I put it in the `else if` that's in the `for` loop

this is a program to check if the 10 digits the user puts in is valid or not

```
#include<stdio.h>

int validateString(char *inStr);
int main()
{
    char stringInput[20];
    printf("Please enter a 10 digit phone number: ");
    scanf("%s",stringInput);
    if (validateString(stringInput)== 1)
    {
        printf("%s is a valid phone number.\n",stringInput);
    }
    else if (validateString(stringInput)== 0)
    {
        printf("%s is not a valid phone number.\n",stringInput);
    }

int validateString(char *inStr)
{
    int i;



    for (i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        if(!(inStr[i] == '0' ||
             inStr[i] == '1' ||
             inStr[i] == '2' ||
             inStr[i] == '3' ||
             inStr[i] == '4' || 
             inStr[i] == '5' ||
             inStr[i] == '6' ||
             inStr[i] == '7' ||
             inStr[i] == '8' ||
             inStr[i] == '9' ||
             inStr[i] == ' ' ))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if ( //the input string is longer than 10 or less than 10)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a method to return the # of chars in a C string, with the understanding that the max # = 20?  Just wanting to clarify that.

Comment: Using a regular expression is probably a better way to validate a phone number.  There are lots of stackoverflow questions about good expressions to use, but what you're alluding to above is roughly "^\s[0-9][0-9 ]+$".  This question shows the C setup for compiling and executing regular expressions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2948043/regular-exp-to-validate-email-in-c - just change from an email regexp to the phone one as above.

Comment: Yeah so that it returns 0 if the input is more than 10 or less than 10

Comment: If you just want to count the digits: `size_t digits = 0; for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i) if (isdigit(s[i])) ++digits;`.  `#include <ctype.h>` for the `isdigit` function.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` should work fine to get the length (number of digits), you just need to make sure the end of the line is terminated with 0. If the input appends a carriage return or line feed on the end, then just replace those values with 0.

```
int main ()
{
    char x[20];
    x[0] = '1';
    x[1] = '2';
    x[2] = '\n';
    x[3] = 0;

    printf("%d\n", strlen(x));
}
```

The above code displays `3`.

If I were to replace index 2 with 0, then I would get the correct count of 2.

`strlen` doesn't give you the total length of an array, it gives you the length of a string terminated with 0.

You also don't need to check for each character, you could do this:

```
if(!(inStr[i] >= '0' && inStr[i] <= '9') || inStr[1] != ' ')
{
    return 0;
}
```

I would also split out the funcationality a bit:

```
int validDigits(char *inStr)
{
    for (int i=0;i<strlen(inStr);i++)
    {
        if(!(inStr[i] >= '0' && inStr[i] <= '9') || inStr[1] != ' ')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int validateString(char *inStr)
{
   return (validDigits(inStr) && strlen(inStr) == 10);
}
```

But, remember to replace any carriage return and line feeds (10 and 13) to zero, otherwise strlen will return a higher number than expected.